# Getting the number of individuals in ontology with OWL API

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

How can I get the number of individuals in ontology regardless to the classes or subclasses they belong to, only by using OWL API (not SPARQL or other tools). 
I was trying this:

```
NodeSet<OWLNamedIndividual> inds = reasoner.getInstances(subClass, false);
int numofInd = inds.getNodes().size();
```

Where `subClass` is a subclass of `Thing`. But how could I get the whole number of individuals in ontology.

Comment: `OWLOntology::getIndividualsInSignature(boolean includeImportsClosure)`, see http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntology.html#getIndividualsInSignature(boolean)

Comment: @AKSW thank you very much! It worked

Comment: @AKSW could you please post your answer as an answer, not a comment, so I can mark it as the proper one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OWLOntology::getIndividualsInSignature(boolean includeImportsClosure)` returns all individuals including the imports closure, see the [Javadocs](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLOntology.html#getIndividualsInSignature(boolean))